# How to display PDF document from memorystream inside WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

I'd like to display in WPF application, PDF documents.

Documents are stored in the database.
I read the document to the memorystream.

**How to display that PDF memorystream inside WPF application - directly from memorystream?**

I don't need any bells and whistles - just display pdf memorystream in WPF app.

Comment: There is nothing like this, as far as I know. But why would it not be possible to save the pdf to a temporary folder and display it with a library ?

Comment: You may use `Windows.Data.Pdf.PdfDocument` via XAML Islands. It has a `LoadFromStreamAsync` method.